# Error app/main.js 404 Not Found on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, angular, kudu, typescript2.0

My angular2 application deployment is clean but when i try to access the url to the same i get the error : app/main.js 404 (Not Found). Also I see no javascript files being created on the go on KUDU. The typescripts files are not compiled as I could make of it. Should i build ts to js on local and then push the js files also on git? Could anyone please suggest what is required to do so.

[image]
PS: My web.config file in root directory is as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My Package.json is :

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.1.0",
    "npm": "3.8.6"
  }, 
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "node_modules\\.bin\\lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install && tsc",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "node_modules\\.bin\\tsc",
    "concurrently": "node_modules\\.bin\\concurrently",
    "tsc:w": "node_modules\\.bin\\tsc -w",
    "typings": "node_modules\\.bin\\typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.14",
    "moment": "^2.15.2",
    "firebase": "^3.5.2",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

If I modify the postinstall command to this I get the ts files compiled to js on kudu but get deployment errors.:

```
"postinstall": "typings install && tsc"
```

I get below error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, Azure Web Apps’ deployment task uses `npm install --production` command to install the dependencies in your `package.json`, which will skips all the dependencies configured in `devDependencies` section.

So first, you can move all the dependencies in `devDependencies` section to `dependencies` section.

As your ts files can be compiled into javascript after the node.js modules installation finished during the deployment task,
 you could use `"postinstall": "typings install && tsc"` instead of  `"postinstall": "typings install && tsc"` to achieve this.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hey Gary.. Thanks for your suggestion. By modifying postinstall command itself I was able to get the js files on kudu. But there is error in deployment. However if i remove the "& tsc" from postinstall command and push the file to git again then the js was already there and the deployment is clean. Could you please telll me why this happens? ******attached the error snapshot in question.******8

Comment: You need to add the following moudles: `"firebase": "^3.5.2", "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.5", "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.14",` to your **dependencies** section.

Comment: It is better not to remove `&& tsc` from postinstall because it rebuilds your ts to js when your ts file is updated.

Comment: after adding the dependencies i am getting npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200. See updated snapshot in question.