# continuously deploy Angular2 app to Azure Web App using Release Management and angular-cli

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, angular-cli

I am currently developing an Angular2 app and want to configure continuous integration and continuous deployment with azure release manager.

Things I got working so far: CI and CD to WebApp, home/site/wwwroot contains source files (no node_modules).

Things not working: App doesn't start. Browsing to url leads to the placeholder (e.g. 'Loading...'). On my local machine I would call 'npm install' and then 'npm start' wich in turn calls 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"'. From my understanding this is fine for a dev environment, but should not be used in production.

Things I have tried:

1. adding 'npm install' to build step leads to extremely long build time bc of the download of the packages and long deployment time bc of the high number of packages
2. adding 'npm install --production' shortens the build and deployment time, but running 'npm start' on the target machine fails because some missing packages (contained in DevDependencies)
3. executing 'npm install' and 'npm start' on the target machine with console seems to work, but can't be automated

So the question(s) are:

1. what is the proper way to build and deploy an Angular2 app on an Azure Web App?
2. How to handle the node_modules?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:** As i switched to angular-cli things are getting clearer now. On my dev machine i use "ng build" and "ng serve" to run locally. For deployment I use "ng build -prod" and deploy the contents of the created "dist" directory to production. Howewer, this is still a workaround as I can't get the build agent to  do these steps. I tried moving the angular-cli reference to "Dependencies" and then call "npm install" and "ng build -prod" on the agent to get the "dist" folder. My Deployment config would then copy the contents of the dist folder to the web app. Then "ng build -prod" step fails

> 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I sort of understand that I can't install and run any package on the build agent, but I would really like to use angular-cli to build the app since it includes webpack. Is there any possibility to get this working as described?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [Custom Deployment Script For Azure Web Apps using Git Deployment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) to achieve your requirement.

Specially for angular2, there are several modifications we should do in the `package.json` file to make the angular2 successfully being deployed to Azure Web Apps.

1. Move all the dependencies modules in `devDependeccies` section to `dependencies` section.
2. Use `"postinstall": "typings install && tsc"` instead of `"postinstall": "typings install"`.

For question 2, you don’t have to push the `node_modules` folder with your project. If you have it declared in your dependencies in your `package.json` then kudu will clone your project and run `npm install –production` to download the correct things.

Comment: Sorry to ask but I'm new to Angular and some concepts still confuse me. Does that mean that the build process simply copies the files over to the vm and kudu runs the "postinstall" script which in turn installs all the node modules? If I'm right, what is the point of building then? How can I measure build quality? And if I move all "DevDependencies" to "Dependencies", what is the point in even using devDependencies? Shouldn't they only be used in development?

Comment: Similar question you can refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231071/error-app-main-js-404-not-found-on-azure)

Comment: Towards your confusing concepts, I'll do some explanations. Once you push your code (through git push) from local git repo to azure remote, kudu will synchronize `repository` to `wwwroot`, then run `npm install --production`, and finally command `postinstall`( the npm script) which will run automatically after the package is installed.

Comment: thanks @AaronChen for the explanation. This means I would "bypass" the azure build and deploy. Is there any way I could integrate those tools in the process? I would love to track the build quality and make use of the other nice features that release management provides.

Comment: Hi @user3838018, basically the deployment and build process is integrated and automated. If you want to control this deployment flow you can use the custom deployment feature, and for more details I would recommend you refer to this great [blog](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/#.WCM_EPl97IU).